# Can I change Button layout runtime?

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to change layout of Buttons in my app in run time. Each page (using `ViewPager`) has different button layout. I wanted to make styles, but better solution is to make separate XML files with each `Button` design and just swap whole layout. But problem with this solution is that I cant actually click on those buttons if I change layout. Even if I set `onClickListener` again after layout swap.

Do you know why is this happening?

Example of button layout swap function:

```
private fun setContinueButtonVariant(){
        val icon = app.resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.arrow_short_flipable, null) as RotateDrawable
        icon.setTint(ContextCompat.getColor(app, R.color.colorText))
        nextBtn = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.intro_button_right, null) as Button
        nextBtn.apply {
            setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null, null, icon, null)
            setOnClickListener {
                goToNextScreen()
            }
        }
 }
```

Comment: just try changing button drawble , it will work perfect . create two drawables and change them on  button click

Comment: problem is that some variants have drawableEnd and drawableStart icons also drawablePadding and some have none. Instead of setting up drawables and its padding programatically every time page will change I wanted to swap whole button.

Comment: why dont you take two button and set their visibilities gone and visible ?

Comment: This can be done too, but i would like to know why this solution doesnt work.